# Disable caching & Destroy Session (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, caching

I have a hyperlink on my dashboard Window(Dashboard.aspx), which i have to use for logging out of the page. For now i've used 'NavigateURL' to redirect it to the main Login page(LoginPage.aspx). On login page i dont want to get back to the dashboard again. BTW, i'm new to this, so i guess i have to disable browser from caching or create session at login and destroying it, etc. **I dont want the user should be able to get back to the dashboard.aspx page on clicking the browser's back button.** Please provide me with the steps/**code(vb.net)** for the same. Looked over the internet, however couldnt able to understand the stuff. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using session to maintain your pages access throughout your application, you can use `Session.Clear()` and  `Session.Abondon()` before redirecting your page to "LoginPage.aspx".

I hope this answers your question. If yes, please mark it as "answered".

Comment: im also using cookies to pass values to labels on other pages. Does i have to clear the cookies or something like that

Comment: if you are passing values to only labels, then there is no need but if you storing some user related information then destroy your cookie by giving expiration time for the cookie.

Comment: i'm passing the username (from the login page) to one of the label on the DashBoard...

Comment: username will not create problem but as a general practice,delete your cookie if you don't require a persistent session.

Comment: if the solution was helpful, please visit my blog codespread.com for more posts.

Answer (score 0):

Before navigating out of dashboard. kill your session by session.abandon.

Comment: resolution sufficient for this issue?

Comment: vote up requires 15 repo lol sorry...i wish i could do it now :)

Comment: i've asked another Q regarding windows authentication..can u have a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632706/windows-authentication-asp-net