# Windows Authentication (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

How i can implement Windows Authentication to authenticate user while logging in? **I do not want to get a pop up window rather i would like to let my login page(LoginPage.aspx) do the same.** Please provide me with the steps/ code(vb.net). Thanks

Comment: @GregSmith new to .NET, also searched it before.. couldnt resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires a good amount of code to access active directory and authenticate.Please refer the article on codeproject.com or msdn articles.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265870/Bypass-Forms-Authentication-to-Use-Active-Director

Comment: welcome, I will also write something on my blog about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use this tag in your web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="60"></forms>
</authentication>
```

And in your login.aspx you would write code to access Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the point about what windows authentication is. Forms authentication can be used when not part of a domain or there is some specific requirement that windows authentication cannot solve. If a computer is registered in an active directory domain, authentication with the web site will be transparent based on the credentials that were used to login to the domain, eliminating the need to supply credentials each time the application is accessed.

Comment: i want to access LDAP directory using vb.net

Comment: Integrated authentication is more than just accessing LDAP